# Elasticsearch results are not very accqurate with my mapping field query

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

Please find my mapping query below for the `filename` field.

```
PUT /articles
{
   "settings" : {
      "analysis" : {
         "analyzer" : {
            "filename_search" : {
               "tokenizer" : "filename",
               "filter" : ["lowercase"]
            },
            "filename_index" : {
               "tokenizer" : "filename",
               "filter" : ["lowercase","edge_ngram"]
            }
         },
         "tokenizer" : {
            "filename" : {
               "pattern" : "[^\\p{L}\\d]+",
               "type" : "pattern"
            }
         },
         "filter" : {
            "edge_ngram" : {
               "side" : "front",
               "max_gram" : 50,
               "min_gram" : 1,
               "type" : "edgeNGram"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings" : {
      "doc" : {
         "properties" : {
            "filename" : {
               "type" : "text",
               "search_analyzer" : "filename_search",
               "analyzer" : "filename_index"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If am trying to query `series1333372 doc623258` and am expecting `karthik_series1333372_oracle_page_doc623258_v1_en-EU.pdf`. But it's giving all the files which is having `series1333372`, not even checking for `doc623258`.

Please find my query below

```
get articles/_search
{
   "query" : {
      "match" : {
         "filename" : "series1333372 doc623258"
      }
   }
}
```

I am inserting the following sample documents for testing from Kibana

```
POST articles/doc/1
{
  "filename" : "karthik_series1333372_oracle_page_doc623258_v1_en-EU.pdf"
}

POST articles/doc/2
{
  "filename" : "karthik_series1333372_sun_page_doc658_v1_en-EU.pdf"
}

POST articles/doc/3
{
  "filename" : "series1333372_oracle_page_doc623_v1_en-US.pdf"
}

POST articles/doc/4
{
  "filename" : "Engineering series1333372 valve_page doc6232 v1_en-US.pdf"
}

POST articles/doc/5
{
  "filename" : "Machines_series1333372_page_doc62258_v1_en-US.pdf"
}

POST articles/doc/6
{
  "filename" : "AIX series1333372 IBM page doc62358 v1_en-EU.pdf"
}
```

Comment: Can you give some example records to play with? Include in your question some entries

Comment: @alkis - updated with sample entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default operator of `match` is `OR`. If you want all your terms to be present change it like this

```
GET articles/_search
{
   "query" : {
      "match" : {
         "filename" : {
           "query": "series1333372 doc623258",
            "operator" : "and"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, what will be java api for this `AND` operator. because i want to execute this query from java code.

Comment: This is a new question. Mark this answer and open a new thread where you will post your java code

Comment: similar to the query, i have raised one question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50849539/java-api-for-elasticsearch-query-with-and-operator